# Why does an action inside an area with out a view render the view from the root controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application with an area for Employee.
In the home controller inside the Employee area i have a two actions :

- Index
- About

[image]

[image]

Index has a view inside the Employee area.
About doesn't have a view in the Employee area.
However, when I navigate to http://localhost:55660/Employee/home/about
It presents me with the About view in the root controller.

Why/how is this happening?...

Comment: It also takes me to that view if I right click on the action and click on 'Go to View' option.  As soon as I add a new view inside the area, it works as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I got the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong here...

I renamed the action to About2 and got this error, and I think this exception answers my question from earlier...

[image]

It looks like mvc looks for the view inside the area first and if it doesn't find it there it looks for it at the root level.